# Can I keep Mail.app from syncing my spam folder?

Tags: mail.app, imap

I finally switched all my email access to IMAP. When I did, Mail.app added synced folders for *Deleted Messages*, *Sent*, *spam*, and *Trash*. Is there any way to tell Mail that I don't want to sync these folders? The *spam* folder only exists for me to occasionally delete its contents and nothing ever shows up in the other three.

I'm running Mail 7.2 under OS X 10.9.2.

[image: Synced folders]

Comment: without knowing WHO is your email provider we can not help you further

Comment: I have a couple accounts at Hostgator and a couple at Hostrocket.

Comment: great, now go there and disable the IMAP service for the Spam folder